# I can't handle resize and transform with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

```
var menuOpen = true;
function MenuOpenClose(){
  console.log($("#left-bar").width());
  if(menuOpen){
    $("#left-bar").css("transform", "translateX(" + $("#left-bar").width() * -1 + ")");
    $("#body").css("width", "100vw");
    console.log("menu was closed");
    menuOpen = false;
  }
  else{
    $("#left-bar").css("transform", "translateX(0px)");
    $("#body").css("width", "calc(100vw -" + $("#left-bar").width() + ")");
    console.log("menu was open");
    menuOpen = true;
  }
}
```

This is my function, when menuOpen I can resize the #body div, but cannot transform the #left-bar. When the menuOpen is false I can't do both of them. What's wrong with code? Btw I use reactjs.

I can get the width in console, but can't resize them.

Comment: When you debug, which operation specifically isn't working as expected?  How is React supposedly involved here?  Can you update the question to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes, if you can please reproduce this in codepen or jsfiddle that would be a alot of help. Also, instead of modifying the css properties in js, have you tried to use js to add a css class that has the transform property?

Comment: Yes, and ı've solved the problem in this way, thanks for your helps.